# MariaDB crashes frequently

Tags: vps, mariadb, debian-buster

I'm suffering from MariaDB crashing issue for a weeks running on VPS Debian 10. I searched a lot in the internet ,but couldn't found any solution. I tried [this](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/17989/why-cant-mysql-access-the-aria-control-file) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61781070/mysqld-out-of-memory-please-take-a-look-at-my-error-log), [this](https://community.easyengine.io/t/mariadb-bin-log-eat-my-disk-space/4278/4) etc... but seriously I didn't found any solution.

This is the MariaDB error log.

```
2021-06-15 17:03:53 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't lock aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' for exclusive use, error: 11. Will retry for 30 seconds
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Could not get an exclusive lock; file is probably in use by another process' when trying to use aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control'
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=1138436566
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.27 started; log sequence number 1138436575; transaction id 567401
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [ERROR] Aria engine is not enabled or did not start. The Aria engine must be enabled to continue as mysqld was configured with --with-aria-tmp-tables
2021-06-15 17:04:24 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

This is my MariaDB config

```
[server]


[mysqld]

performance_schema = on
user                    = mysql
pid-file                = /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket                  = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir                 = /usr
datadir                 = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir                  = /tmp
lc-messages-dir         = /usr/share/mysql
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
query_cache_size = 32M
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci
innodb_file_per_table = 1
thread_cache_size = 8
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
read_buffer_size = 2M
sort_buffer_size = 2M
table_open_cache = 512
max_allowed_packet = 512M
key_buffer_size = 384M
[embedded]

[mariadb]

[mariadb-10.3]
```

There is no spike in the server resources. At the time of checking this was the usage stats.

```
0.44 (1 min) 0.27 (5 mins) 0.15 (15 mins)
```

When this error occurs , I kill the proccess id manually and restart the server. This is how I'm dealing with the situation now. I chekced whether there is any folder permission issues in /var/lib/mysql but it is fine, the ownership is mysql:mysql.

You may check the complete error log [here](https://justpaste.it/8w5e0).

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: What does `ls -l /var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control` say?  Was this recently upgraded to 10.3?

Comment: @RickJames - The output is `-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 52 Jun 15 22:19 /var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control` . No, I was never upgrade MariaDB server.

Comment: An [internet search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=%22Could+not+get+an+exclusive+lock%22+%22%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fmysql%2Faria_log_control%22&ia=web) brought up a few results, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085279/mysql-cant-lock-aria-control-file. You may also get something out of the [lslock tool](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85994/how-to-list-processes-locking-file).

Comment: @berndbausch - I really tried a lot of options that is available in the internet , but none of them works. I applied some solutions in my server that I seen in some techincal docs, but there is no heal for this issue. The one of the link you shared here is for raspberry-pi , but in my case the server environment is totally different. Its debian 10 +apache2.4.38+mariadb10.3. In most of the solutions , they're suggesting reinstalling the mariadb server. I'm checking is there any possibility to fix this issue without reinstalling it, because there is alot of production websites on my VPS.

Comment: @KiranRS When will you tell us how much RAM is on the server?

Comment: @WilsonHauck- I had upgraded MariaDB to 10.6.4 and issue got resolved.